# A weaker version of the Firoozbakht's conjecture

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Firoozbakht's conjecture states that: $p_{k}^{1/k}$ is a strictly decreasing function of $k≥1$. Here $p_{k}$ is the sequence of primes.

I know that is statement is not yet proved. But I am asking on a **weaker** version:

Show that there exist infinitely many indices $k$ such that $$p_{k+1}^{1/k+1}<p_{k}^{1/k}$$

This question is relevant because I want to see the behavior of this sequence over an infinite set.

Comment: What did you try to get an answer to this? What is the nature of the reference-request tag here?

Comment: @quid: I mean if there is some references talking about this.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's an easy consequence of known results.

Comment: The following is overkill; it is known that there are inifinitely many k with $p_{k+1} < p_k +1000$. For large k that implies you inequality. Sorry I don't speak Russian.

Comment: On your edit, as I explained, it's an easy consequence of well-studied questions. It's not a relevant way of inquiry, in my opinion.

Comment: Otherwise we had $p_n \geqslant c^n$ for some $c > 1$ and $\sum \frac{1}{p}$ would converge.

Comment: $\lim_{k \to \infty}p_k^{1/k} = 1$ implies $p_k^{1/k}$ is decreasing for most $k$

Comment: Small prime gaps such as prime twins , prime cousins , sexy primes etc work here. In fact your claim is proven by the recent prime gap results.